# .import in sqlite3 through prompt

Tags: import, sqlite, command-prompt

I was trying to import a csv file through prompt doing:

.mode csv

.import 'filepath' table

but that didn't work ihave to put the csv file in the sqlite's .exe folder to work.
my question is why, can't i import a csv from another folder?

many thanks

Comment: Use the full path to the file.

Comment: i used it 'C:\Users\jo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\airbnb\reviews.csv' but it gave me this error Error: cannot open "C:\Users\jo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\airbnb\reviews.csv"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if using non-ascii characters is an issue due to how Windows works. Or the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

So the way i found to not move the csv for sqlite's folder is to change the work directory:

To see in what directory you are in:

**.shell cd**

To change directory to the csv's folder:

**.cd 'fullpath directory of csv you want'**

Then just import the csv(you can use the relative path):

**.import '.\name.csv' tablename**